# My issue is same as many others sent BTC but funds were not received

Tags: lost-transactions

even though the transaction shows as confirmed the receiver has not received the funds. I looked on Blockchair by entering the receivers wallet address and doing a history search and guess what it shows my transaction fully completed..??? so where are the fund?s?